# URL isn't displayed when using natbib and gerplain bibliographystyle

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, online

I would like to use following reference in my bibtex-file:

```
@online{Iyer,
author = {Iyer, Ratliff, Vijayan},
title = {Algorithms for Vertex Ranking of Weighted Graphs},
subtitle = {Research Experiences for Graduate Students in Combinatorics 2013},
url = {http://www.math.illinois.edu/~dwest/regs/rankwt.html},
organization = {University of Illinois},
year = {2013},
urldate = {02.05.2017},
}
```

Unfortunately the URL doesn't get displayed, only the title and the authors. 
I'm using the following

```
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{gerplain}
```

If I change the bibliographystyle to plainnat, the URL appears, but I have to use the gerplain. Do you have any ideas, what could be a problem?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) looking in the code, the URL field is not supported at all by that bibtex style. I would be surprised if it was even compatible with `natbib`. If you **have** to use this style, your best bet is probably to include the URL in the note field manually, including the formated URLDATE.  The style originates from 1985(!) and does not seem to have been updated since 2003.

Comment: That entry is for the modern biblatex system, it cannot be used with the older bibtex system by default. The urldate field has the wrong format.

Comment: Same here, if adding \bibliographystyle{chronological} it currently kills the URLs. Not clue as of now, I'm debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for some reason, you can't switch to using biblatex, you may want to look into using the `natdin` bibliography style instead of the ancient `gerplain` style. (URLs were not widely used at all in the late 1980s...) Oh, and do please correct the `author` field: use the keyword `and` (not commas) to separate authors, and do provide the authors' given names.

Several additional issues: since the `natdin` bibliography style doesn't recognize the entry type `@online`, the default or catch-all entry type `@misc` will be used for the entry at hand. Because the `@misc` entry type isn't programmed to recognize fields named `subtitle`, `organization`, and `urldate`, you should (a) combine the contents of the `title` and `subtitle` fields and (b) use the field names `howpublished` and `note` instead of `organization` and `urldate`, resp.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@online{Iyer,
author       = {Iyer, Ananth V. and Donald H. Ratliff and Gopalakrishanan Vijayan},
title        = {Algorithms for Vertex Ranking of Weighted Graphs. Research
                Experiences for Graduate Students in Combinatorics 2013},
url          = {http://www.math.illinois.edu/~dwest/regs/rankwt.html},
howpublished = {University of Illinois},
year         = {2013},
note         = {Last checked: 2.5.2017},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{natdin}
\usepackage[spaces,obeyspaces,hyphens]{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{Iyer}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```